# Importance of PHP in web oriented platforms

Tags: php

Why is PHP the most used programming language for a web based platform?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the statistics you're referencing, for some context.

Comment: The Tiobe index is a good reference for that: http://www.tiobe.com/index.php/content/paperinfo/tpci/index.html

PHP is #3 on the list, which is pretty good for a "single purpose" language. Many big company / government sites run on Java EE or JSP though, so this is not a real proof.

Answer (score 7):

PHP:

- is easy to learn;
- has been around for ~15 years;
- runs fairly efficiently;
- is cheap to host; and
- actually scales really well (some of the largest sites on the internet use it).

PHP is basically the ultimate grass-roots success story.

Comment: Is easy to learn "Hello world!" in php, but its not so easy to learn how to write 'good code'.

Comment: Realistically "working" code is all that's needed (for large values of "working").

Comment: One example of a large site using php is facebook.

Answer (score 3):

PHP is:

1. Built for the web, that is not an extension of an existing language like Perl.
2. Free of any default framework; this allows it to be fairly lightweight and powerful, a good example of the KISS (Keep It Simple, Stupid) principle.

Answer (score 2):

Because software that values simplicity over everything else propagates faster.

Answer (score 2):

Probably because PHP is easy to learn and it was really simple at first start. With the upcoming of `OOP` from PHP4 we cannot really say it's simple anymore but at least it tries to keep simple.

Plus from the start the language was really Web oriented, easy access to get/post variables.

You can also note the PHP community is really wide and Zend do a great job to make it a real concurrent of Java/Dotnet/all the others.

Perl/Python/Ruby are also good scripting language but they require some libraries to develop web application

Answer (score 2):

While most CGI language extensions require you to write HTML/JS/CSS within that languages syntax, PHP is able to be used within the contents of an HTML file structure.  For someone who doesn't really get the concept of CGI (like I did a while back), it's really nice and offers room to grow with libraries and a universally familiar syntax.

Answer (score 2):

1. It's also a **strategic** isue to
   choose PHP over Java/Ruby/...
   Because you will find PHP
   programmers every time, but it is
   really difficult to get (cheap)
   Java/Ruby/... programmers.
2. PHP has become the **third most be
   liked programming** language. [*](http://langpop.com/) [**](http://www.tiobe.com/index.php/content/paperinfo/tpci/index.html)
3. Its **Open Source**.
4. Its old and therefore **very stable**.
5. Its the **best documented** language in the internet.
6. It has the **most string functions** (necessary for web/HTML programming).
7. It has a **very huge community**, you will find the answer for every PHP question in the internet (or ask stackoverflow).
8. Its the only language which was **designed for the internet**.

Comment: Your are right, but from a strategic business administration point of view: a bad programmer is better than none!

Answer (score 1):

PHP is fairly easy to install and fairly easy to understand.  For that matter, you don't even have to install it.  Fifteen dollars a month (or less) will get you a PHP webhost at hundreds of hosting companies.

There are no shortage of "Build a website in 5 minutes with PHP" books.  Therefore, it's often the first choice to new web developers or people who want to get something done quickly.

PHP certainly has it warts, but done properly, it can be a good solution as well.  Despite its warts, it runs an awful lot of successful websites.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is easy to learn, it is faster, it has lots of forums, it has lots of example codes, it has ...

Answer (score 0):

A lot of emerging php framework like Symfony, Zend, and Cake make rapid development, good mvc design easy. A lot of extremely popular blogging software/cms's are built using php eg. Drupal, Wordpress, and Joomla!.